# Get file property value by name using Reflection on _oledocumentproperties.SummaryProperties instance

Tags: c#, file, system.reflection

Investigating on the web, the only examples I found to get a file built-in property value like 'Author', 'DateLastSaved' or 'Company' look like this:

```
string filePath= @"C:\Users\ME\Desktop\PaperSpecs.docx";
DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties file = new DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties();
file.Open(filePath, false, DSOFile.dsoFileOpenOptions.dsoOptionDefault);

Console.WriteLine("Author: " + file.SummaryProperties.Author.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("DateLastSaved: " + file.SummaryProperties.DateLastSaved.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Company: " + file.SummaryProperties.Company.ToString());
```

Let's consider to retrive a value by the property name... I mean to implement a function with two parameters: i) a `DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties` instance; ii) the property name (`string propName`).
My first idea, but I think the "most stupid way" also, consist in implementing a switch-case that check the `propName` value and then, depending on that value, returns the related `_oledocumentproperties.SummaryProperties` property... that is:

```
...
string val= null;
switch(propName)
{
  case case "Author":
   val= file.SummaryProperties.Author.ToString(); break;
  case case "DataLastSaved":
   val= file.SummaryProperties.DataLastSaved.ToString(); break;
  ...
  default: throw new Exception("Property not found");
 }
return val;
```

But I don't like this solution, it is "too long" to write and "not easy" to mantain. Maybe there is a better way to implement this function... for example using the power of C# Reflection! I'm not very good to handle Reflection but I've tried to do something like that:

```
...
Type t = file.SummaryProperties.GetType();
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo p = t.GetProperty(propName);
object value = p == null ? null : p.GetValue(file.SummaryProperties, null);
return value.ToString();
```

The problem is that the `p` instance is always `null`!!!

**My question is:** Do you know a better way to implement the function that I'm looking for? Or can you adjust my last code hint to resolve my problem through Reflection?
 Thanks guys!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fa1ac430-add4-4d17-a278-518669c02977/get-file-property-value-by-name-using-reflection-on-oledocumentpropertiessummaryproperties?forum=csharpgeneral&prof=required) is the answer... Reflection won't work with COM objects.